# Arduino stop process if no move anymore how to fix

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

Hello i have problem :

state sensor = sensor steps "IF" anyone "steps now = impulse " = all code run"perfect good work im happy" but if sensor LOW a did not detect any motion while loading the code = broke stop all , even if it is at the end close or halfway, it will stop when there is no traffic "" (stage_sensor ==         HIGH)"", i dont have idea how to fix this//

Please help or sugestion

EDIT : There may be syntax errors (is not consistent), but just wanted to present a problem, the system only works under "if" and this is problem, i dont know how to fix

```cpp
#include <AccelStepper.h> //accelstepper library

// #define light
// #define move_sensor
// #define water_pump
// #define fan_blowing
// #define fan_extractor
// #define blue
// #define red
// #define green

const byte limitSwitch_1 = 26;
const byte limitSwitch_2 = 25;
bool switchFlipped = false;
bool previousFlip = true;
int switchCounter;
int newSpeed;
int state_sensor = 0;  // <--- stage sensor //
int light = 2;
int blue = 3;
int red = 4;
int green = 5;
int fan_blowing = 6;
int water_pump = 8;
int move_sensor = 9;
int fan_extractor = 10;

AccelStepper stepper(1, 22, 23);

void setup()
{
    pinMode(water_pump, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(light, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(fan_blowing, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(fan_extractor, OUTPUT);  
    pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(move_sensor, INPUT);
    pinMode(limitSwitch_1, INPUT_PULLUP);  //pin 1 engine (IF touch)
    pinMode(limitSwitch_2, INPUT_PULLUP);  //pin 2 engine (IF touch)

    Serial.begin(9600);

    stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);
    stepper.setAcceleration(100); 
    stepper.setSpeed(1000);

    delay(500);
}

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(light, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);

    state_sensor = digitalRead(move_sensor);
    if (state_sensor == HIGH)   // <--- stage sensor IF anyone move = all code run but if sensor LOW did not detect movement all code broke stop all //
    {
        digitalWrite(blue,     LOW);
        digitalWrite(red,     HIGH);
  
        stepper.runSpeed();
        engine();
    }
}

void engine() 
{
    if(digitalRead(limitSwitch_1) == LOW)
    {
        switchCounter++;
        delay(1000);

        newSpeed = -1 * (1000 + (switchCounter * 200));
        stepper.setSpeed(newSpeed);
    }

    if(digitalRead(limitSwitch_2) == LOW)
    {
        switchCounter++;
        delay(1000);

        newSpeed = -1 * (1000 + (switchCounter * 200));
        stepper.stop();
        fans();
    }
}

void fans()
{
    digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
    {
        digitalWrite(fan_blowing, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(fan_extractor, HIGH);

        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(water_pump, HIGH);
    }

    delay(1000);

    digitalWrite(red, LOW);
    digitalWrite(water_pump, LOW);
    digitalWrite(green, HIGH);

    delay(1000);

    digitalWrite(fan_blowing, LOW);
    digitalWrite(fan_extractor, LOW);
    digitalWrite(green, LOW);
    digitalWrite(blue, HIGH); //this blue RGB light "ON" but if sensor_steps "ON" = active cycle , blue light led off

    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: please help , anymore question please write i broke 2 moth. on this i try use INT State but i broke or i wrong write code

Comment: "there may be syntax errors" you need to post the EXACT code that shows the problem and works. How do we know where the actual problem lies if you don't post the actual code?

Comment: `accelstepper:72:36: error: 'sensor_move' was not declared in this scope
         state_sensor = digitalRead(sensor_move);
` This code does not compile.

Comment: state_sensor = digitalRead(move_sensor);       ====       state_sensor = digitalRead(sensor_move);                 i fix this UP check its compile now @JohnFilleau problem is , all code work but IF state_sensor = digitalRead.... = LOW (no see movement anymore all machine stop)

Comment: Are you asking why `digital_read(move_sensor);` appears to keep returning `LOW`? What device is connected to pin 9, and what other pins is that device connected to? This appears to be a hardware problem.

Comment: @JohnFilleau the principle by which he wants it to work is if it detects motion the whole process fills up, but if there is no motion while the process is running the process stops working

Comment: @JohnFilleau the problem in my opinion is that the code works, but it only works on one condition "if (state_sensor == HIGH) // <" and the problem is that if it does not detect motion, the process stops and detection takes only a short time

Comment: @JohnFilleau I want the process not to break down. in the absence of movement, when it is already run, but the impulse on the pin is one and not continuous, maybe the problem is with the code

Comment: @JohnFilleau the condition is on the "IF" itself maybe there is a way beyond

Comment: @JohnFilleau I tried to add a global variable   /  INT stage  / void setup  stage = 0 / and  examples "if(stage == 1 && digitalRead(limitSwitch_1) == LOW)" but the engine doesn't start like that, maybe I supplement it badly without knowing C ++ fully

Comment: @JohnFilleau if (sensor status == HIGH) = sensor detected motion
if (sensor status == LOW) = sensor did not detect motion  , if output pin my process dont work i know but how to fix and process if start all completed "if sensor status = low" and process run / sorry  my english

Comment: @JohnFilleau 9 pin , if i input this pin all run and start process but if run and output this pin my code stop

Comment: What I'm hearing is that you want a single detection to start the engine. We can accomplish that with a state machine. But when do you want the engine to turn off?

Comment: if digitalWrite(blue, HIGH); = end the code// and// check on flop = if digitalWrite(blue,     LOW); = check move i thinks is the key of the problem but how check i write on code "//this blue RGB light "ON" but if sensor_steps "ON" = active cycle , blue light led off" if you have plan or construct this code please write @JohnFilleau

Comment: I'm sorry, but the language barrier is too much to understand. If you can define in plain language (not computer code) what you want the system to do, then you can translate THAT into code. Right now I understand you want to turn a fan on when it senses motion. But I don't know what will trigger the fan to ever turn off. Do you want it to ever turn off? Figure out the plain language description, then turn THAT into code.

Comment: I would like the engine and all processes to work,even when the motion sensor changes to LOW , unfortunately my code is built on the principle: if there is movement, the process starts, but it is enough that during this process the motion sensor LED turns off and the process stops , I do not know how to write the code differently so that the program, despite starting, does not stop working in the middle , due to lack of movement after the process running , now its understand me ? @JohnFilleau

Comment: btw. what is exposed is a process of operation on such a principle because I cannot implement a global variable in this code ... tell me your sugestion for this @JohnFilleau

Comment: check this @Anonymous1847